# Form interferes with rails routes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, post, routes

I have a question that I couldn't solve by myself, so I'd appreciate any help. It concerns my Rails application which contains a user authentication.

The problem is, that I want to have an input form for a search function that posts the input to a new page that handles the search query.
But it doesn't work, because Rails sort of thinks, that the POST belongs to the whole user authentication thing, and redirects me to the login page.

So the question is, how do I separate this one input form from all the rest. I thought I'd maybe need a new controller for the search, but the whole search thing is not handled by Rails, but by a JavaScript.

Here are some details:

In routes.rb:

```
controller :sessions do
  get 'login' => :new
  post 'login' => :create
  delete 'logout' => :destroy
  get 'logout' => :destroy
end
```

And the form in application.html.erb:

```
<div class="btn-group" style="height: 20px;">
<form action="/#search" method="post">
    <input id="search" type="text" class="search-query span2" placeholder="Search Our Database">
    </form>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript/CoffeeScript that handles the form (this function is called when 'URL/#search' is called:

```
displaySearch = ->

  str = $("#search").val()

  html = "You have just searched for "
  html += "<strong>" + str + "</strong>"

  $("#appCanvas").html html
```

I'd greatly appreciate your tips on how to solve this problem :)
Thanks a lot, and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to prevent the form from being submitted? Then you just have to stop the event or return false in your callback method.

```
$(myForm).submit -> false
```

I'm afraid that you've tried to use /#search as an actual URL to post to. You should know that anchors (#search) are not being transfered to the server so Rails just can't route this and assume a normal POST action on the current URL.

If you want to handle it via Javascript, implement it with AJAX. Otherwise you really should make a new controller/action for this.